# Binding To ICommand From Inside DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datatemplate

I have a custom control that has an ICommand dependency property. I would like to bind to this property from inside a DataTemplate. To make things clearer here's my code:

**DataForm class:**

```
public class DataForm : Form
{
    #region Properties

    public ICommand HideForm
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(HideFormProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HideFormProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HideFormProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HideForm", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DataForm), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    #endregion

    #region Ctors
    public DataForm(Guid formId, String title)
        : base(formId, title)
    {
        this.Template = Application.Current.Resources["DataFormDefaultTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
    }
    public DataForm()
        : this(Guid.NewGuid(), "bla")
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        if (HeaderTemplate == null)
        {
            HeaderTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultFormHeaderTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        }
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**ControlTemplate of the DataForm:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="DataFormDefaultTemplate" TargetType="my:DataForm">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"></ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding BodyTemplate}"></ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"></ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**The DataTemplate from which I want to bind to the HideForm command:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DefaultFormHeaderTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <my:TextField FieldViewStyle="{StaticResource formLabelStyle}" Value="Form Title" Mode="View"></my:TextField>
        <my:ImageButtonField ImagePath="../Images/Popup_Close.png" 
                         CommandToExecute="{Binding HideForm}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="8" Height="8"></my:ImageButtonField>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

*Note: `CommandToExecute` does work properly on the ImageButtonField. I've already tested it.*

**Code to instantiate the DataForm:**

```
    DataForm form = new DataForm();
    form.BodyTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["DataFormBodyTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    form.FooterTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["DataFormFooterTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

    form.HideForm = new DelegateCommand(CloseIt);
```

How do I get this to work? Basically, the perfect scenario is to be able to bind to this command (and other properties) in the data template from the **ViewModel** without having to add that property (`HideForm` in this case) to the `DataForm` class. Shouldn't the **DataContext** be inherited and - theoretically - what I'm saying should work?

Comment: Nobody other than you has your `Form`, `TextField` nor `ImageButtonField` classes, so nobody other than you can run this code to find out what the problem is.  In particular, how does a `Form` use a `HeaderTemplate`?  Try providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: @Luke Woodward: That's going to be quiet hard because there are several classes in the inheritance chain but I'm pretty sure the problem is with the DataTemplate. I want to know whether what I'm trying to achieve is possible or is it a limitation by Silverlight 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that there is no way to get this done with a `DataTemplate` unless you use a [Binding Proxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx). The other way around is to use a `ControlTemplate` instead and bind to the `Template` property of a `ContentControl` instead of using a `ContentPresenter`

Answer (score 0):

I use [EventToCommand](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) in [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), see example code below.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl x:Key="ViewModel" Content="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

.. Your code here ..

<my:ImageButtonField ImagePath="../Images/Popup_Close.png" 
                     CommandToExecute="{Binding HideForm}" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="8" Height="8">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Content.YourCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</my:ImageButtonField>
```

You can read more about [EventToCommand](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/) <- here.